# SHINY: "Chained" reactivity with sliderInput, dateRangeInput and selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to solve more complicated case of reactivity in my shiny app. 
My dateRangeInput and selectInput constrain a dataframe which I am plotting into leaflet map. Also, there is a sliderInput that constrains the same df. So far so good.

But I need the slider's min and max values to be reactive as well. Specifically I need the values to change based on filters applied to the df with dateRangeInput and selectInput.

I have tried to make the slider reactive by generating it on the server side, but I haven't found the way how to use the slider input for the filtering of the df. And the same vein, I haven't found a way how to plug reactive min and max values to sliderInput when rendered on ui side.
Thank you for a hint.

Comment: Try to use `observeEvent()` with a list of all these reactive values for the `eventExpr` argument, and update all you need in the `handlerExpr` argument.

Comment: thx for the answer. So if I understand it correctly, you would render the slider on the server side, right?

Comment: Yes, I do not know any other way

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I can work from here.